Make <svg> input required
I have the html code below that I adapted from the fifth answer in this post Capture Signature using HTML5 and iPad to collect a signature with a form. The problem I am having however is that a user can submit the form without creating a signature (signing). Does anyone know how I can make it required for the form to submit?


<svg id="sig_panel" viewBox="0 0 300 100">
   <rect id="r" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#ffa"/>
   <line x1="0" y1="80" x2="300" y2="80" stroke="#000000" 
      stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="3" 
      shape-rendering="crispEdges" pointer-events="none" />
   <path id="p" stroke="navy" stroke-width="2" fill="none" 
      pointer-events="none"/>
</svg>
<div class="flex">
  <button id="clear">Clear signature</button>
</div>




You may check for the length of the d attribute. In this moment the path has no d attribute or length = 0. For a valid signature you may ask for a certain length

Do you know would I go about doing that? Would it require Javascript?

Yes: you would need to get the value of the d attribute and then get the length of the string. It shouldn't be a problem since the answer you mention is allready using JS

You may also write the svg output to a hidden text input and make this field mandatory/required

The example below is a modified version of the code in this answer. It features a <form> that submits to a live test server and uses a hidden <textarea> to store the signaturePath and ensure that there is a signature before the <form> can be submitted by the use of the required attribute.

First, click the "Submit Signature" button. <form> will not submit and a popup should appear.

Next, write a signature in the yellow area and then click the "Submit Signature" button. The <form> will submit the value of the <textarea> and a response from the server will be displayed in the <iframe>.


Details are commented in the example.


const svg = document.getElementById("sig"),
  rSVG = document.getElementById("rect"),
  pSVG = document.getElementById("path"),
  form = document.getElementById("signature"),
  data = document.getElementById("data"),
  clear = document.getElementById("clear");

let signaturePath = "",
  isDown = false;

function isTouchEvent(e) {
  return e.type.match(/^touch/);
}

function getCoords(e) {
  if (isTouchEvent(e)) {
    return e.targetTouches[0].clientX + "," + e.targetTouches[0].clientY;
  }
  return e.clientX + "," + e.clientY;
}

/**
 * Functions down(), move(), and up() will assign signaturePath
 * to textarea#data [value]:
 *     data.value = signaturePath;
 */

function down(e) {
  signaturePath += "M" + getCoords(e) + " ";
  pSVG.setAttribute("d", signaturePath);
  isDown = true;
  if (isTouchEvent(e)) e.preventDefault();
  data.value = signaturePath;
}

function move(e) {
  if (isDown) {
    signaturePath += "L" + getCoords(e) + " ";
    pSVG.setAttribute("d", signaturePath);
  }
  if (isTouchEvent(e)) e.preventDefault();
  data.value = signaturePath;
}

function up(e) {
  isDown = false;
  if (isTouchEvent(e)) e.preventDefault();
  data.value = signaturePath;
}

rSVG.addEventListener("touchstart", down, false);
rSVG.addEventListener("touchmove", move, false);
rSVG.addEventListener("touchend", up, false);
rSVG.addEventListener("mousedown", down, false);
rSVG.addEventListener("mousemove", move, false);
rSVG.addEventListener("mouseup", up, false);
rSVG.addEventListener("mouseout", up, false);

function clearSignature() {
  signaturePath = "";
  pSVG.setAttribute("d", "");
  data.value = "";
}

clear.addEventListener("click", clearSignature);

/**
 * Clears signaturePath and path#path [d] attribute when form#signature
 * is successfully submitted.
 */
function clearSVG() {
  signaturePath = "";
  pSVG.setAttribute("d", "");
}

form.addEventListener("submit", clearSVG);
svg {
  margin: .5em;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: .5em;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: .5em;
}

button {
  margin: .5em;
}

iframe {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  margin: .5em;
}

/**
 * <textarea id="data required> is hidden from user.
 */

#data {
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  margin-top: -15px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 0;
  resize: none;
}
<!--
  - Wrap everything in a <form> (aka form#signature).
  - form#signature will send the signaturePath to a live test
    server if the <textarea id="data" required> (aka textarea#data) 
    has [value] (ie text). 
  - If textarea#data doesn't have any [value], then form#signature 
    will not submit and a popup prompts user with,
    "Please fill out this field". 
-->
<form id="signature" action="https://httpbin.org/post" method="post" target="response">

  <svg id="sig" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="100" viewBox="0 0 300 100">
  <rect id="rect" width="300" height="100" fill="#ffa"/>
  <line x1="0" y1="80" x2="300" y2="80" stroke="#666" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="3" shape-rendering="crispEdges" pointer-events="none"/>
  <path id="path" stroke="navy" stroke-width="2" fill="none" pointer-events="none"/>
</svg>
  <!--
    - textarea#data needs [name] attribute in order to submit it's [value]
      to the server.
    - [required] attribute ensures that form#signature will not submit
      if textarea#data [value] is false (ie '').
    - textarea#data styles conceals it from users (see CSS #data).
  -->
  <textarea id="data" name="data" required></textarea>

  <div class="flex">
    <!--
      If a <button> doesn't actually submit a <form>, add  
      [type="button"] to it.
    -->
    <button id="clear" type="button">Clear Signature</button>
    <!-- 
      Plain <button> will submit form#signature when clicked.
    -->
    <button>Submit Signature</button>
  </div>

  <!--
    If form#signature is successfully submitted (200), this <iframe>
    will display the server response. Look for form.data to
    review the signaturePath (ex. "data": "M131,76 L131,76 L131,76 ...").
  -->
  <iframe name="response"></iframe>

</form>



